# Encountered an internal server error 500 while using CloudBees Folder plugin

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I just installed 'CloudBees Free and Open Source Jenkins Plugins' on our Jenkins instance today. When I tried to use the 'CloudBees Folder Plugin', an internal server error 500 showed up in the 'Configure' page right after I created a folder.

It seems that the class of 'com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/domains/DomainCredentials' was missing on my Jenkins and I have no idea about what's going on here.

Jenkins version: Jenkins ver. 1.516.JENKINS-14362-jzlib

Regards,
Paxson Yang

> Status Code: 500
>
> Exception: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/D:/CI/Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.516.JENKINS-14362-jzlib.jar!/lib/form/block.jelly:32:22:  com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/domains/DomainCredentials
>   Stacktrace:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/D:/CI/Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.516.JENKINS-14362-jzlib.jar!/lib/form/block.jelly:32:22:  com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/domains/DomainCredentials
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:103)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:583)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:214)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
>     at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
>     at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
>     at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
>     at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
>     at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208)
>     at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
>     at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:86)
>     at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:84)
>     at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:98)
>     at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
>     at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>     at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
>     at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>     at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:64)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>     at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
>     at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>     at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>     at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>     at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>     at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
>     at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>     at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>     at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
>     at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:227)
>     at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>     at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/D:/CI/Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.516.JENKINS-14362-jzlib.jar!/lib/form/block.jelly:32:22:  com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/domains/DomainCredentials
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:745)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:289)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.WhenTag.doTag(WhenTag.java:46)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ChooseTag.doTag(ChooseTag.java:38)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:81)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:146)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.OtherwiseTag.doTag(OtherwiseTag.java:41)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ChooseTag.doTag(ChooseTag.java:38)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.OtherwiseTag.doTag(OtherwiseTag.java:41)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ChooseTag.doTag(ChooseTag.java:38)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.WhenTag.doTag(WhenTag.java:46)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ChooseTag.doTag(ChooseTag.java:38)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:81)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:95)
>     ... 62 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/domains/DomainCredentials
>     at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.properties.FolderCredentialsProvider$FolderCredentialsProperty$DescriptorImpl.defaultIfNull(FolderCredentialsProvider.java:194)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
>     at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
>     at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
>     at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
>     at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
>     at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
>     at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:74)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.StaticTagScript.run(StaticTagScript.java:111)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>     at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>     ... 187 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class was [introduced in credentials-plugin 1.5](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/commit/ea696cb21bc84bbe756334ef818450405432410a), please double check you have the latest version installed.

Comment: @Jesse Glick, I upgraded the Credentials-Plugin and the error is gone. However, I am confused by the link of 'Add Existing Jobs' because it takes me to 'http://<HOST>/job/___Internal_Jobs___/configure' and I cannot add jobs on that page. I think that it should take me to 'http://<HOST>/job/___Internal_Jobs___/view/<VIEW_NAME>/configure' for adding existing jobs to this folder. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your question about the _Add Existing Jobs_ link would best be filed separately.